# Java Executor in timerange at specific time

Tags: java, executors

I need to call a task every x hour in a defined time range and repeat this every day.
My only idea is to calculate the executions times as delay from current time and start each in a seperated thread via scheduleAtFixedRate and a rate of 24 hours.
Do anyone has a better idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use your machines in built task schedule to call a script and call your java program from that script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library dedicated to schedule code: [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

It use `cron` like syntax and can schedule `Job` implementations.